# Zooming with an iframe is only changing the width of the frame

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe in my site that allows a user to view the source for the information contained on the page. I want them to be able to zoom in and out, but every single example I find that zooms the element only seems to increase or decrease the width of the iframe (or object, I've tried to do that too) for me. This isn't the exact code I'm using, but it is an example of something I found and tried which didn't work.

```js
var img = $('#image-container iframe');
var zoomWidthIncrement = img.width() * 1 / 3;
var zoomHeightIncrement = img.height() * 1 / 3;

$("#zoom-in").click(function(e) {
    img.css({
        width: img.width() + zoomWidthIncrement,
        //height: img.height() + zoomHeightIncrement
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#zoom-out").click(function(e) {
    img.css({
        width: img.width(function(i, w) {
            return w - zoomWidthIncrement;
        }),
      //  height: img.height(function(i, w) {
       //     return w - zoomWidthIncrement;
       // })
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image-container">

    <iframe src="https://asascreener.elementfx.com/cdc-hiv-prep-guidelines-2021.html">
    
    </iframe>

</div>
<br>
<div id="image-controls">
     <input id="zoom-in" value="+" type="submit" />
     <input id="zoom-out" value="-" type="submit" />
</div>
```